# Is there a way to implement floating damage numbers with java.swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

I'm creating a game using Java Swing, and I'm finding the need for graphical displays of what's going on at this point.  The current display uses a grid of JButtons to represent the tiles on a battlefield.  Would it be possible to display floating/disappearing damage numbers over the JButtons, using perhaps custom made pixel art GIFs? If so, how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Swing components can be extended to change its presentation.

Create an own button class extending `JButton` and override its `paintComponent` method to display the required damage. This method receives a `Graphic` (actually an instance of `Graphics2D`) on which you can draw the damage, if one is *active*.

Very simple example:

```java
public class DamageButton extends JButton {

    private String damage = null;

    public DamageButton(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void setDamage(String damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
        System.out.println(damage);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (damage != null) {
            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            try {
                gg.setColor(Color.RED);
                gg.drawString(damage, 10, 10);
            } finally {
                gg.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Creating a new `Graphics` (`gg`) so the settings of `g` are not changed and need not to be restored.</sup>

Call `setDamage()` with some text to have it displayed over the button  or with `null` to cancel the effect.

Animation or other effects can (more or less) easily be added. Just be aware that the given `Graphics2D` has a clipping area set to the dimension of the button.